# How to create an Email share button on Fancybox 3 buttons

Tags: mailto, fancybox-3

If I enable the Share button I see 3 functions: Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest. Is it possible to create an email share button? I have only worked out how to do it as a text link within the data-caption area which appears below the image, see below code.

```
    `<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="imagejpg" data-caption="Image name<a href=&quot;mailto:email&#64;example.com&quot;><u>send this image by Email</u></a>"><img src="image.jpg" height="250" width="auto" alt="" ></a>`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `share : { tpl : '...'}` that contains template for share dialog. You can use to do your customization.